# Force UiInterfaceOrientation from Landscape to Portrait?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I know may be it's a duplicate question, but I tried many answers described here and I can't get it working from hours.

I'm working on an application for IOS 6 and IOS 7, just I need to move from my first viewController "A" which is on Landscape orientation, to a second viewController "B" which is on Portrait orientation.

I configured the project to enable all desired orientation, set the "appropriate" code, but still get the second view displayed vertically on a landscape orientation..

[image]

here is the code I set for first controller :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:      (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape ;
}
```

Plz help.

Comment: your code is correct and it will work just put your all these methods in each view controller according to desired outputs.

Comment: when I put the same code on my second controller, with portrait orientation, I get this error :'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES' so I changed it to NO to get rid of this error, and I get the same as the image above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the UINavigationViewController methods(`pushViewController:animated:` and popViewControllerAnimated:), the views will inherit the previous view's orientation.

On the other hand, if you use `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` methods, everything works perfectly.

[Also here is a sample project which is also changing orientation as required by you](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zw3qesn8w4v66hy/Archive.zip)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, I'm just adding my views by [firstVieController.view addSubView:secondViewController.view]; isn't there a method to do this correctly?

Comment: Yes in this way you can also get your desired orientation